Disable npm registry in Deno vendored application
My Deno application is using npm dependencies
import { 
    ServiceProvider, 
    ServiceProviderInstance , 
    IdentityProvider, 
    IdentityProviderInstance,
    setSchemaValidator } from 'npm:samlify@2.8.10';

When I vendor it, it produces the following deno.jsonc:
{
  "tasks": {
    "start": "deno run --allow-all src/server/main.ts --production"
  },
  "nodeModulesDir": true,
  "importMap": "./vendor/import_map.json"
}

However, when I run it in my production environment, which is NOT connected to the interned, I get the following error:
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error getting response at https://registry.npmjs.org/samlify for package "samlify": error sending request for url (https://registry.npmjs.org/samlify): error trying to connect: dns error: No such host is known. (os error 11001): error trying to connect: dns error: No such host is known. (os error 11001): dns error: No such host is known. (os error 11001): No such host is known. (os error 11001)

How do I get rid of this?

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]? For additional information, see [ask]. Also, did you see the documentation for deno vendor, which suggests running the application using the argument --no-remote?

These are the minimal information required for the case, The --no-remote doens't work. BTW, I'm posting now the solution I could find with Deno documentation. Thanks anyways!

I've found the solution.

After vendoring, add a package.json file listing your node dependencies. In my case:

{
    "dependencies": {
        "@authenio/samlify-node-xmllint": "*",
        "samlify": "^2.8.10"
    }
}


then run npm install to resolve all dependecies of the npm modules being used.

include the generated node_modules in the delivery package

Launch the production (vendored) version using the --unstable-byonm option (also added --no-remote but not sure it's actually needed)


--unstable-byonm actually tells Deno not to try to resolve dependencies and use what is in package.json and node_modules
